# no-touch deployment

Tags: vb.net, web-deployment

I am finding all sorts of general descriptions of no-touch deployment and lots of questions and problems, but I can't figure how to just get started with it. What is the method that makes it happen? I'm working in VB.Net 2005. I think assembly.loadform will suit me best since I know all of my users and will deploy via my intranet.

Appreciate any links or suggestions for starting places (other than googling "no-touch deployment", I already did that).

Comment: The technical phrase for this is "Continuous Integration". That should help your search efforts. Other than that,though,this question is too general to typically be considered on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's a web application project that you're deploying, one-click publish with Web Deploy may be what you're looking for. Here's a related link:

[How to: Deploy a Web Application Project Using One-Click Publish and Web Deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)